# Configure: error: Curl library not found on centos 7

Tags: centos7, curl, zabbix

I want to install zabbix 2.4.5, but when I type:

```
./configure --enable-server --enable-agent --with-mysql --enable-ipv6 --with-net-snmp --with-libcurl --with-libxml2
```

I get some problem:

```
Configure: error: Curl library not found

[root@pc-bello zabbix-2.4.5]# rpm -qa | grep curl
libcurl-7.29.0-35.el7.centos.x86_64
curl-7.29.0-35.el7.centos.x86_64
python-pycurl-7.19.0-19.el7.x86_64
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to install an old version of Zabbix from source?

Comment: i just tried to install this zabbix. i dont know the latest version. how the latest version zabbix now?
Thanks

Comment: this is not the latest version? i read in google, zabbix-2.4.5 is the latest version

Comment: Obviously you were reading the wrong site. Go to the official site and you will learn the latest version. Then just install it from EPEL.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to answer your implicit question, you also would have to install the `-devel` packages of `curl` to compile Zabbix on your own.

```
yum install libcurl-devel
```

It might be that there are more `-devel` packages needed.

But if you just want to install Zabbix, use the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) or even better use the repository of Zabbix directly. Follow the install manual [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/installation/install_from_packages/repository_installation) to add the repository. Then follow the manual.